# Okta Auth Login

Tags: angular, okta

*tl;dr: After executing `await oktaAuthService.login('/');` the next instructions are being skipped.*

I have the following:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {OktaAuthService} from '@okta/okta-angular';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  this.user = undefined;
  constructor(private oktaAuthService: OktaAuthService, private bkndSrv: BackendService) {}
  
async login() {
    await this.oktaAuthService.login('/');
    // the next 2 lines are not being executing!
    this.user = await this.oktaAuth.getUser();
    console.log("user: ", this.user);
  }
```

When I call to the `login()` function I am being redirected to the okta login page and I am successfully being redirected back with token. However, I don't see the log on the screen and the `this.user` remains undefined even after the login functions finished.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, refactoring to the `.then` notation did it. i.e.

```
  login() {
    this. oktaAuthService.login('/').then(() => {
      this. oktaAuthService.getUser().then((user) => {
        this.user = user;
        console.log('user: ', this.user);
      });
    });
  }
```

**But, if anyone knows how to do it with async-await, please share!**